# Python как записать строку "\x**", например (\x4b), самим байтом в wb файл

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

Открыв бинарно pdf файл, пытаюсь его сохранить в новый файл, открытый для записи бинарно. но вместо символов оказываются записи типа \x00\x14QE\x00\xa2\x8a. Как это исправить.

```
f = open('1.pdf', 'rb')
str_b = f.read()
f.close()

f2 = open('2.pdf', 'wb')
f2.write(str_b)
f2.close()
```

Comment: Точно `f2 = open ('2.pdf', wb)`, а не `f2 = open ('2.pdf', 'wb')`? Да и как открывали `2.pdf` чтобы увидеть записи типа \x00\x14QE\x00\xa2\x8a?

Comment: Открывал в Kate. С кавычками, верно, это я переписывал.

Comment: Приведённый вами код вроде бы не может так сделать. Вы уверены, что это [mcve]? Вы запускали именно этот код и всё равно получали эту проблему?

Comment: Код минимально адаптирован к проблеме. Читаю pdf я с потока http, и вопрос стоит в  том что нужно \x8a\x27 байты байтими и записать, а не символикой

Comment: Нет, давайте ещё раз: вы запускали ИМЕННО ЭТОТ код и получали с ним проблему? Про http забудьте - в показанном вами коде никакого http нет.

Comment: именно этот работает)

Comment: @Владимир, а Kate умеет pdf показывать?

Comment: это же текстовый редактор

Comment: @Владимир ну тогда мы ничем помочь не сможем, так как не видим вашей проблемы. Приведите [mcve], который продемонстрирует проблему

Comment: @Владимир, а у pdf не текстовый формат, а бинарный

Comment: байтово показывает

Comment: pdf-файлы не являются текстовыми, и открывать их в Kate или любом другом текстовом редакторе нет смысла. Впрочем, к сути вопроса это не относится, вы нам код с проблемой покажите